# How far does Banach algebra technique apply to local fields setting?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, number-theory, analysis

This is related to Lang Real and Functional Analysis Chpt XVI sec 1 and 2.

Thm 1.2 $A$ is commutative banach normed algebra over real with unit $e$. Assume $A\ni j$ s.t. $j^2=-e$ and complex number $C=R+Rj$. Given $v\in A-\{0\}$, there is $c\in C$ s.t. $v-ce$ is not invertible.

Thm. A normed field over real is either $R$ or $C$.

This is proved by invoking above theorem to to a field extension of normed field containing $C$. Then it follows from field property that only $0$ being non-invertible. Hence any element of the normed field must be an element of complex number. The real case follows trivially by dimension reason.

$\textbf{Q:}$ For Ostrowski theorem, it classifies the valuations over $Q$. Here valuation induces a metric which is a norm over the field. So above Thm indicates that $\infty$ place is $R$ or $C$. Is there a proof by Banach algebra technique to prove classification of valuation of $Q$ over finite places? First $Q_l$ is not algebraically closed. So I guess the nature of the problem differs significantly here.

$\textbf{Q':}$ How far does Banach algebra technique apply to local fields setting? In other words, how frequently do I need algebraic closure property or maybe I could just live with $\overline{Q_l}$ where $l$ is a prime.